# glBufferData() not updating buffers outside of the main function?

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, glm-math

In my code I have a function called CompileRawBufferData(), this function compiles my array of custom classes into raw data that the buffer can read. The array of `VBufferObject`s is really just the same as the normal data, except with a bufferSignature so I can identify the object when I need to delete it from the buffers. VBufferObject looks like this:

```
namespace Vega
{
    class VBufferObject
    {
    public:
        unsigned int bufferSignature;

        std::vector<unsigned int> IBD;
        std::vector<glm::vec3> VBD;
        std::vector<glm::vec2> UVBD;
        std::vector<glm::vec3> NBD;
    };
}
```

This is then passed into my CompileRawBufferData() function which looks like this:

```
void VInstance::CompileRawBufferData
(
    std::vector<unsigned int>& IBD,
    std::vector<glm::vec3>& VBD,
    std::vector<glm::vec2>& UVBD,
    std::vector<glm::vec3>& NBD
)
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> IBData;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> VBData;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> UVBData;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> NBData;

    for (VBufferObject object : objectBuffer)
    {
        IBData.insert(IBData.end(), object.IBD.begin(), object.IBD.end());
        VBData.insert(VBData.end(), object.VBD.begin(), object.VBD.end());
        UVBData.insert(UVBData.end(), object.UVBD.begin(), object.UVBD.end());
        NBData.insert(NBData.end(), object.NBD.begin(), object.NBD.end());
    }

    IBD = IBData;
    VBD = VBData;
    UVBD = UVBData;
    NBD = NBData;

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBD.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &VBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBD.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &UVBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NBD.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &NBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBD.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &IBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
```

So everytime I want to update the objects in a scene (add or delete them) I call:

```
Loader::LoadObject("OBJECT PATH", objectBuffer, newestSignature);
CompileRawBufferData(IBD, VBD, UVBD, NBD);
```

The LoadObject() function loads and adds the new object to the objectBuffer and then I compile the raw buffer data to be assigned to each of the buffers.

When I use the glBufferData() in the main function like this:

```
    GLuint VertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBD.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &VBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    GLuint UVBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &UVBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBD.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &UVBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    GLuint NormalBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &NormalBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NormalBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NBD.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &NBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    GLuint IndexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBD.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &IBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

It works perfectly fine, however, in the CompileRawBufferData() function (above) it does not update the buffers, and doesn't cause any errors either. NOTE: I am 100% that this is not the fault of the object loader. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the buffers, I need to bind them like so:

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBD.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &VBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBD.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &UVBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NormalBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NBD.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &NBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBD.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &IBD[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Instead of calling glBufferData by itself. Credit to genpfault for the answer.